# Flutter RefreshIndicator does not work when there's only one page

Tags: flutter

Flutter RefreshIndicator does not work when there's only one page. Did I use it the right way? Thanks!
If you change the `pages` with two or more pages, and drag down on the first page, the indicator works fine. But when there's only one page, it can't be dragged down.

Sample Codes:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Bar(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class Bar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _BarState();
}

class _BarState extends State<Bar> {
  List<Widget> pages;

  final controller = PageController(initialPage: 0, keepPage: true);
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    pages = [_makePage('page 1')]; //, _makePage('page 2')];
    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: _onRefresh,
      child: PageView(
        controller: controller,
        children: pages,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      ),
    );
  }

  Future _onRefresh() async {
    print('refresh!');
  }

  _makePage(String s) {
    return Center(child: Text(s));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Flutter docs, that is expected behavior for RefreshIndicator.

Please refer **[RefreshIndicator class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html)**

The RefreshIndicator will appear if its scrollable descendant can be overscrolled, i.e. if the scrollable's content is bigger than its viewport. To ensure that the RefreshIndicator will always appear, even if the scrollable's content fits within its viewport, set the scrollable's Scrollable.physics property to AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics.

Please see the working code below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = const Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Test',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Bar(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class Bar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _BarState();
}

class _BarState extends State<Bar> {
  List<Widget> pages;

  final controller = PageController(initialPage: 0, keepPage: true);
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    pages = [_makePage('page 1')]; //, _makePage('page 2')];
    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: _onRefresh,
      child: PageView(
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: controller,
        children: pages,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      ),
    );
  }

  Future _onRefresh() async {
    print('refresh!');
  }

  _makePage(String s) {
    return Center(child: Text(s));
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh! That's what that part means! I had read that doc, and what was in my mind was list view. So silly of me XD Thank you! Now with this I see what pageView really is - a scrollable view bigger than screen - same as list view.